# how to extract sinhala and other non english words using regex

Tags: regex

I need to extract non english words using regex. I used following code as pattern 
to extract those non English words but i cannot do so..

```
refid=27">[\w\s]+
```

This is the source

```
you are in</h3><ul class="br"><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/516524655403741?refid=27">සුරතල් සතුන් හා කුරුල්ලන් රැක බලා ගැනීම හා අලවිය . (Caring &amp; Selling pets)</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">2</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/172049482926284?refid=27">Online Entrepreneurs Club</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">4</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/150397831690139?refid=27">Online හෙල්ප්</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/1476405172417700?refid=27">Online Help - ඔන්ලයින් හෙල්ප්</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/354104358026264?refid=27">Online HELP</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/804276106323782?refid=27">Genius club   දිනියස් එකතුව மேதாவி கழகம்</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/1613330538980720?refid=27">විසිතුරු මසුන් (visithuru masun)</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/253488828388200?refid=27">MISHA AND SRI LANKAN SQUIRREL&#039;Sමිෂා හා ශ්‍රී ලංකාවේ ලේන්නු</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">24</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/262540340854681?refid=27">fish talk SRI LANKA | ලංකාවේ අපේ මාළු කථා</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/191754987600288?refid=27">සත්‍ය හොල්මන් කථා (Sathya holman katha)</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/296742820347262?refid=27">Online Help</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/1552966808313507?refid=27">Sri Lankan People</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">21</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/253336874833199?refid=27">සුරතල් සතුන් ඇතිකරන්නන්ගේ එකමුතුව</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/829614997099717?refid=27">SL PC Gamers | පරිගණක ක්‍රීඩා ☑️</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/314556931977559?refid=27">විසිතුරු ලෝකය/Charming World.</a></td><td class="n"><span class="bt bu">25</span></td></tr></tbody></table></li><li class="bj"><table class="m bs" role="presentation"><tbody><tr><td class="t"><a href="/groups/1691732991063409?ref
```

Using following pattern i can extract english words not non english words properly.. could anybody suggest me a method to do it.. I want to do this via REGEX only
Thanks

Comment: What about using `[\x00-\x7F]+` (same as `[ -~]`), or keeping spaces `[\x21-\x7F]+` (same as `[!-~]+`)?

Comment: not working. it is not extracting sinhala fonts

Comment: Use replace with that. The idea is to replace everything ASCII and only non-ASCII remains.

Comment: i replaced , it is not extracting other not english words

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester please check your answer here

Comment: See it in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/iWyeKT/1). The substitution result is what you want.

Comment: Or [this](https://regex101.com/r/iWyeKT/2) to keep proper spacing

Comment: Try `\b[\p{L}\p{M}-[a-zA-Z]]+\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you method is working, but not 100%

Comment: @ctwheels thank you. these are source code of facebook groups.. some groups title has sinhala words and english words. i want to extract both. could you have any method?

Comment: Could you please explain what should be precised? What is the rule / rules here? If you also need to match spaces you may use `\b[\p{L}\p{M}-[a-zA-Z]]+(?:\s+[\p{L}\p{M}-[a-zA-Z]]+)*\b`.

Comment: Actually i want to extract group tiltles. those come with english + sinhala + tamil names or other language names. I want to extract that title...

Comment: So your post title requires adjustment. Add the expected result and pattern specifications to the question but it looks like a duplicate now.